# Extracting Base Object From Derived Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class `A` and a class `B` which derives from `A`. I have an instance of `B`, namely `b`, which I want to extract just the `A` part from. Something like :

```
var b = new B(); 
A a = (SomeCast)b;
```

The catch is `a.GetType()` should return `A` Type not `B`.

Is it possible without creating an instance of `A` and manually copying all fields and properties from `b`?

Update
The root of problem originates from Entity Framework which does not allow derived types to be added in place of base type. I have a biiig derived type (which I am not allowed to add annotations to) and want to add only the base part to database.

I am just curious that is there a simple answer.

Comment: Basic polymorphism concludes that `b` *is* an instance of `A` for all intents and purposes.  `A a = b;` is logically an instance of `A`.  Why do you also need `GetType()` to demonstrate that?  Taking a step back, what's the problem being addressed here?

Comment: The root of problem originates from Entity Framework which does not allow derived types to be added in place of base type. I have a biiig derived type (which I am not allowed to add annotations to) and want to add only the base part to database.

Comment: You should definitely add that context to the question, along with perhaps an example of the attempt to use the variable in EF and the error it causes.  This could very well be more of an EF question than a polymorphism question, and you'll want to make sure the question attracts the right expert attention.

Comment: Thanks David, the problem started from EF, but now I'm just curious that is there a simple answer to that or should I just do the long job.

Comment: I've added the `Entity-Framework` tag for clarity, as that will help narrow the context of why this question is being asked. Though I'd suggest the OP does add some EF related context to the question also.

Comment: What do you mean EF doesn't allow derived types to be add in place of the base type? You can use the derived type anywhere you use the base type including adding it to a DbSet or a collection of child properties.

Comment: Which EF version are you using?

Comment: Can you add the error message given by EF along with a minimal code example that generates it?

Answer (score 0):

If `B` inherits from `A`, them all instances of `B` will be too instances of `A`, all fields and properties of `A` are available in an instance of `B`.

In your code, you don't need to cast, just make the assign:

```
var b = new B();
A a = b;
```

But do not need this, you can work with `b` as an instance of `A`, without creating the variable `a`.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, but a.GetType() returns B, not A.

Comment: Surely if a.GetType() returned A then you'd lose all the extra stuff you had in B? I'm thinking object slicing here. The whole "does not allow derived types to be added in place of base type" is really weird. I suppose if the objects were copied by value then you'd have the slicing problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Ugly code ahead*

Well, i'm going to risk myself to receive a lot of negative feedback, but let's see if this is what OP wants.

As everyone already told you,there's no way to "strip" the derived to the base class. So what i'm proposing here is just a hack using reflection.

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }

    public A(B inhClass)
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(A).GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = typeof(B).GetProperty(prop.Name);
            prop.SetValue(this, myPropInfo.GetValue(inhClass, null), null);
        }
    }
    public string a { get; set; }
}

public class B:A
{
    public string b { get; set; }
    public A baseclass
    {
        get
        {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }


}
```

As you can see, in class B I add a new Property returning a new instance of A using a new constructor in class A. This new constructor loops all properties in base class and get the value from the derived class.

That's it, I'm opened to public lynching :)